# autotest not working on Windows 7 32 bit

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, autotest

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl and am not having any luck getting autotest working.

When I run the "autotest" command I get the following output in my terminal:

> C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>autotest
>   loading autotest/rails_rspec2
>
> ---
>
> ←[2J←[fbundle exec C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.8.7\bin\ruby -S C:/RailsInstaller/Rub
>   y1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/bin/rspec --autotest 'C:/Sites/ra
>   ils_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
>   bundler: command not found: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.8.7\bin\ruby
>   Install missing gem binaries with `bundle install`
>   Notification sent successfully
>   Notification sent successfully

Then it just stalls and I have to cntrl+c to get out of it.

When I try running a "bundle exec autotest" i get the following output:

> C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>bundle exec autotest
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib/bundler/ru
>   bygems_integration.rb:143:in `gem': ZenTest is not part of the bundle. Add it to
>   Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
>          from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/bin/autotest:18

I have the following content in my .autotest file:

> require 'autotest/growl'

and my gemfile looks like this:

> source 'http://rubygems.org'
>
> gem 'rails', '3.0.7'
>   gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'
>
> group :development do
>       gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
>   end
>
> group :test do
>     gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
>     gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
>   end

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ZenTest may not have installed correctly. You could try `gem install ZenTest` and see if you get a different result running `bundle exec autotest`. If that doesn't work, maybe try adding ZenTest to your Gemfile.